# C# Struct this() initializer - Memory, Performance, and cleanliness

Tags: c#, .net, performance, struct, garbage-collection

Resharper recommended a change to my .net struct that I was unaware of. I am having a hard time finding Microsoft information about the **this()** initializer on a struct.

I have a constructor on my struct where i am passing in the values, but want the struct properties to be read-only to once the struct has been created.   The Resharper proposed way makes the code much cleaner looking.

*Questions:*

- Memory: I want to avoid generating any extra garbage if possible. I worry using this() may pre-initialize my value types, prior to setting them.
- Performance: I worry that using the this() will first initialize the struct values with defaults, then set the values. An unnecessary operation. It would be nice to avoid that.
- Cleanliness: Its obvious that using the **:this()** makes the struct much cleaner. Any reason why we wouldn't want to use that?

Example:

```
public struct MyContainer
{
    public MyContainer(int myValue) : this()
    {
        MyValue = myValue;
    }

    public int MyValue { get; private set; }
}


public struct MyContainer2
{
    private readonly int _myValue;

    public MyContainer2(int myValue)
    {
        _myValue = myValue;
    }

    public int MyValue
    {
        get { return _myValue; }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to optimize performance and less .net garbage, which is the correct route to go?  Is there even a difference when it gets compiled?

I don't want to blindly accept using this, when I am creating millions of structs for data processing. They are short lived container objects so .net garbage and performance matters.

Comment: I think you misread the refactoring: the cleanliness comes from auto-properties, not from `this()` call.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The latter is a necessary change in order to use the former.

Comment: Setting a location in memory to zero, and then immediately setting it to something else, wouldn't generate garbage.  Garbage is created by creating new object instances, which *can't* happen as a result of this change.

Comment: @Servy so you suggest that `:this()` is much cleaner than C# 6 version where you no longer need that strange `:this()`? I don't see `:this()` as "makes the struct much cleaner." - just unfortunate side effect of language design...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Calling the default constructor before calling the parameterized constructor is necessary as a result of the change to using auto-properties.  Whether the call to the default constructor is explicit or implicit is irrelevant to that point.

Comment: @Servy I thought you were defending OP's statement that "Its obvious that using the :this() makes the struct much cleaner", thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a quick benchmark of a struct with the "this()" initializer and one without, like this:

```
    struct Data
    {
        public Data(long big, long big2, int small)
        {
            big_data = big;
            big_data2 = big2;
            small_data = small;
        }

        public long big_data;
        public long big_data2;
        public int small_data;
    }
```

I benchmarked by initializing 5 billion structs of each type.  I found that in debug mode, the struct test without "this()" initializer was measurably faster.  In release mode, they were almost equal.  I am assuming that in release mode, the "this()" is being optimized out and in debug it is running the "this()" and possibly even initializing the struct fields to default.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short coming of the language concerning auto implemented properties and structs. It's fixed in C# 6 where the explicit call to `this` is not necessary , and you could even do away with the private setter:

```
public struct MyContainer
{
    public int MyValue { get; }
    public MyContainer(int value)
    {
         MyValue = value; //readonly properties can be set in the constructor, similar to how readonly fields behave
    }
}
```

As to performance. I'd be very much surprised if there is a noticeable difference between the two (I can't currently check the differences in the generated IL). (*As per comments, the next bit of the answer is irrelevant, calling `this()` will not generate additional "garbage"*) Also, if the objects are short lived like you claim, I wouldn't worry about garbage at all as they would all be stored in the stack, not the heap memory.

Comment: the `this` is now implicit, but while you don't need to include it explicitly, it's still doing the same thing.  If that change is problematic, for whatever reason, then nothing about it would change.

Comment: I'm sure any extra cpu cycles its hardly measurable and worth talking about. But the initialization of a backing field prior to the setting of the value is what had me curious.  Are we technically pre-allocating that with a default value type, then setting it with a new one? The operation is what has me curious.

Comment: Side note: last sentence  (full of autocorrect errors) spreading misinformation - being value type has nothing to do with where value is stored ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/ )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if you'd bothered to read careful you'd realize that I did not say that a value type is in the stack. I said that a *short lived* value type will be in the stack. There is quite a difference between the two.

Comment: @TravisWhidden You are contradicting yourself in your comment.  If you don't care about a few CPU cycles, then why would you care if a few CPU cycles are spent setting a few memory addresses twice instead of once?

Comment: @InBetween At best that bit is a red herring.  Whether the struct is short lived or not is irrelevant in this context, as is whether it's stored on the stack, heap, or anywhere else.  Don't even bring it up as it's entirely off topic.

Comment: @Servy well the OP mentions *garbage* which is a rather confusing and undefined term. I might have erroneously linked it to garbage collection and memory pressure, hence my comment.

Comment: @InBetween I also assume it means managed garbage.  My point is that it doesn't matter the context in which the constructor is called, or where the actual value of the struct being initialized is, no additional garbage can possibly be created as a result of calling the default constructor vs. not calling it.  Whether the memory being initialized is on the stack, heap, or elsewhere, setting that memory to zero before calling the constructor *can't* generate garbage, thus your qualification that it only applies under certain circumstances is unnecessary, and potentially confusing.

Comment: @Servy ok, understood now, yeah, your right, it's not relevant to the question. I'll edit that part.